# oracle sql request column ambiguously defined

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, ora-00918

I am working on oracle 11g and tried to execute this request

```
select code_mod,INTITULE,code_et,nom ,avg(note)
from note,exam,module,etudiant
where note.CODE_EX = exam.CODE_EX 
and EXAM.CODE_MOD=MODULE.CODE_MOD
and NOTE.CODE_ET = ETUDIANT.CODE_ET
group by code_mod,code_et 
order by code_mod;
```

but it says!

```
 ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error on line 6, colunn 19
```

what is wrong in it? if I execute this request, it works

```
select *
from note,exam,module,etudiant
where note.CODE_EX = exam.CODE_EX 
and EXAM.CODE_MOD=MODULE.CODE_MOD
and NOTE.CODE_ET = ETUDIANT.CODE_ET;
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago!) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have at least two of `code_mod`,`INTITULE`,`code_et`,`nom` columns in `note`,`exam`,`module`,`etudiant` tables, and put them without aliases.

As an example both `module` and `exam` table include `code_mod` column, and in the select list you didn't show where it comes from

Use like this :

```
select m.code_mod,intitule,et.code_et,nom ,avg(note)
  from note n
 inner join exam e on ( n.code_ex = e.code_ex )
 inner join module m on ( e.code_mod=m.code_mod )
 inner join etudiant et on ( et.code_et = n.code_et )
group by m.code_mod,intitule,et.code_et,nom 
order by m.code_mod;
```

and you should include all columns in `group by` expression without `grouping functions`.

Comment: already tried it before, but ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"

Answer (score 0):

You have column with the same name in more than one table involved in the query, so you must prefix the column with proper table name eg:

```
select 
    EXAM.code_mod, INTITULE, EXAM.code_et, nom, avg(note)
from 
    note, exam, module, etudiant
where 
    note.CODE_EX = exam.CODE_EX 
    and EXAM.CODE_MOD=MODULE.CODE_MOD
    and NOTE.CODE_ET = ETUDIANT.CODE_ET
group by 
    EXAMcode_mod, EXAM.code_et, INTITULE, nom
order by 
    EXAM.code_mod;
```

Comment: I tried it before asking the question, but it says

Erreur SQL : ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"

Comment: answer  update with all the column not in aggregation function in group by